# On hover have div expand height over all other divs, Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

http://mw.ecologik.net/projects/

Test project here. I am trying to get my divs, on a hover to expand with the new content. I get this done using simple jQuery but could use css as well.
The issue I am having is that I am asking bootstrap to go against its rules. I want that div on hover to go OVER the divs below so I don't get the white space. I have seen it done on other sites but they are not using the BS model. Any thoughts? My code is repeating `col-sm-4` in a row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change to something like this

```
<div class="col-sm-4 each-proj pl-0 pr-0" style="height: 250px; border: 10px solid white; z-index: 100; overflow: unset;">
```

Don't change the `height: auto` to just leave it on `250px;` but give it `overflow: unset;`
And for a div that has content, add `background: #fff;`

[image]

Comment: Never heard of the unset. Thanks! It works EXCEPT the border doesn't seem to want to grow with the overflow:unset.  Why does the border not come with it?

Comment: Resolved the issue. Put the border on an inner div and not the one I am unsetting. Works like a charm. Thanks!